# asp.net using mvc 3 applying kendo ui

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

sir can anyone lend me a hand in fixing my program.. im using kendo ui in my asp.net mvc. the problem is the records in the database is not being display everytime i run the program it just display nothing.and indicate a error.. saying "{"The entity or complex type 'database.APPLICANT' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query."}"

here is my controller:

```
  private IQueryable<APPLICANT> GetApplicant()
    {
        var applicants = (from a in dbContext.APPLICANTs
                          select a).Take(50).ToList();

        return applicants as IQueryable<APPLICANT>;
    }

    public ActionResult GetApplicant([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
    {
        return Json(GetApplicant().ToDataSourceResult(request));
    }

    public ActionResult UpdateCustomer([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, APPLICANT applicant)
    {
        var customerToUpdate = dbContext.APPLICANTs.First(app => app.APPLICANT_ID == applicant.APPLICANT_ID);

        TryUpdateModel(customerToUpdate);

        dbContext.SaveChanges();

        return Json(ModelState.ToDataSourceResult());
    }

    public ActionResult InsertCustomer([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, APPLICANT customerToAdd)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            dbContext.APPLICANTs.Add(customerToAdd);
            dbContext.SaveChanges();
        }

        return Json(new[] { customerToAdd }.ToDataSourceResult(request));
    }

    public ActionResult DeleteCustomer([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, APPLICANT applicant)
    {
        var customerToDelete = dbContext.APPLICANTs.First(app => app.APPLICANT_ID == applicant.APPLICANT_ID);

        if (customerToDelete != null)
        {
            dbContext.APPLICANTs.Remove(customerToDelete);
            dbContext.SaveChanges();
        }

        return Json(new[] { customerToDelete }.ToDataSourceResult(request));
    }
```

my context:

```
  public partial class APPLICANT
    {
        public int APPLICANT_ID { get; set; }


        public string APPLICANT_LastName { get; set; }
        public string APPLICANT_FirstName { get; set; }
        public string APPLICANT_MiddleName { get; set; }
        public string APPLICANT_Address { get; set; }

        public string APPLICANT_City { get; set; }
        public string APPLICANT_ZipCode { get; set; }

        public string APPLICANT_Phone { get; set; }

        public string APPLICANT_Email { get; set; }


    }
```

index:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}
<h2>@ViewBag.Message</h2>

@(Html.Kendo().Grid<KendoGridMvcCodeFirst.ViewModels.APPLICANT>()
    .Name("APPLICANT")
    .ToolBar(tb => tb.Create())
    .Pageable()
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource.Ajax()
        .Model(model => model.Id(c => c.APPLICANT_ID))
        .Read("GetAPPLICANT", "Home")
        .Update("UpdateCustomer", "Home")
        .Create("InsertCustomer", "Home")
        .Destroy("DeleteCustomer", "Home"))
    .Columns(cols =>
    {
        cols.Bound(c => c.APPLICANT_LastName).Width(200);
        cols.Bound(c => c.APPLICANT_FirstName).Width(200);
        cols.Bound(c => c.APPLICANT_MiddleName).Width(200);
        cols.Bound(c => c.APPLICANT_Address);
        cols.Bound(c => c.APPLICANT_City);
        cols.Bound(c => c.APPLICANT_ZipCode);
        cols.Bound(c => c.APPLICANT_Phone);
        cols.Bound(c => c.APPLICANT_Email);   

        cols.Command(cmd =>
        {
            cmd.Edit();
            cmd.Destroy();
        });
    })
)
```

*what is missing in my codes? thanks for those who can help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the return flag Jason behave allow get.

```
Json(new [] { customerToAdd }.ToDataSourceResult(request),JsonBehavouir.AllowGet);
```

Comment: still getting the error.. i edited my query code because my database is already created so i only have to fetch the data on the database

Comment: Try putting your fields of APPLICANT before ([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request. If that does not work can you examine what APPLICANT is on the controller?

Comment: sir i already edited my code above the error message is gone but another one appear and this is it.... 
{"Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: source"} .. what do you think causing this error.. by the way im using database first so i have to fetch the records that is on my database

Comment: tnx sir i already make it work... by the way sir do you know how to add a search function in here.. i only know search function in asp.net mvc but i dont have any idea how if i apply kendo ui.. tnx

Comment: There is an AutoComplete widget that is supported in the MVC framework also. Here is a link to the example page: [http://demos.kendoui.com/web/autocomplete/index.html]